# pip3 abort signal on startup

Tags: homebrew, python, catalina

I've just upgraded to macOS Catalina, I've used `brew install dpkg`, and homebrew decided it was time to run `brew cleanup`.

After running it, I've not been able to run pip3 anymore.

Tried running `brew doctor` and `brew reinstall python3`, but none helped.

Running pip3 outputs this:

`[1]    26346 abort      pip3`

Answer (score 3):

That problem is caused by asn1crypto.
You could try:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asn1crypto*
```

Which will uninstall asn1crypto.

Reference:
[This Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272830/python-crashing-on-macos-10-15-beta-19a582a-with-usr-lib-libcrypto-dylib)

Comment: I was skeptical, but this answer did indeed solve the issue for me.

Comment: great to know it helped!